# How to isolate dy/dx in this equation?

Tags: calculus

$$e^{\sin y}\cos y\left(\frac{dy }{dx }\right)=5x^4\arctan y+\left(\frac{x^5 }{y^2+1 }\right)\left(\frac{dy }{dx }\right)$$

---

The correct answer is:

$$\frac{dy }{dx }=\frac{5(y^2+1)x^4\arctan y }{-x^5+y^2e^{\sin y}\cos y +e^{\sin y}\cos y}$$

---

My answer is different, and I don't know what I'm missing:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/erxUz.jpg

Comment: $f(y)\frac{dy}{dx} =g(x,y) +h(x,y)\frac{dy}{dx}$ from this we can re-arrange by collecting terms with $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and factorise. So you will end up with $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{g(x,y)}{f(y)-h(x,y)}$$. Can you sub in the functions you have in your problem into the above? If so it's a case of simplifying.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{\sin y}\cos y\left(\frac{dy }{dx }\right)=5x^4\arctan y+\left(\frac{x^5 }{y^2+1 }\right)\left(\frac{dy }{dx }\right)\\
\left(\frac{dy }{dx }\right)\left(e^{\sin y}\cos y - \frac{x^5}{y^2+1}\right) = 5x^4\arctan y\\
\left(\frac{dy }{dx }\right)\cdot\frac{e^{\sin y}\cos y(y^2 + 1) - x^5}{y^2 + 1} = 5x^4\arctan y$$

Any clearer now?

Answer (score 0):

You simplify the denominator (you have already solved) and simply get the answer.